# How to extract a string following a pattern using unix(mac OSX)

Tags: macos, unix, awk, grep

I have file with these columns and tab separated.

```
Jun-AP1(bZIP)/K562-cJun-ChIP-Seq(GSE31477)/Homer    12.88%  4926.5  9.08%
Maz(Zf)/HepG2-Maz-ChIP-Seq(GSE31477)/Homer  52.08%  25510.3 47.00%
Bach2(bZIP)/OCILy7-Bach2-ChIP-Seq(GSE44420)/Homer   10.81%  4377    8.06%
Atf3(bZIP)/GBM-ATF3-ChIP-Seq(GSE33912)/Homer    28.73%  13346.9 24.59%
TEAD4(TEA)/Tropoblast-Tead4-ChIP-Seq(GSE37350)/Homer    40.43%  19549.3 36.01%
```

In first column, I want to extract the string upto first bracket and keep rest of the columns same.
For instance, I need the output as shown below.

```
Jun-AP1 12.88%  4926.5  9.08%
Maz 52.08%  25510.3 47.00%
Bach2   10.81%  4377    8.06%
Atf3    28.73%  13346.9 24.59%
TEAD4   40.43%  19549.3 36.01%
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/\(.*Homer/,"")}{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file

Jun-AP1 12.88% 4926.5 9.08%
Maz 52.08% 25510.3 47.00%
Bach2 10.81% 4377 8.06%
Atf3 28.73% 13346.9 24.59%
TEAD4 40.43% 19549.3 36.01%
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with

```
sed 's/([^ ]*//'
```

where that's an actual tab character in `[^ ]`.

Comment: It works perfect without '(' in your answer. i.e. sed 's/\[^ ]*//'

Comment: @EdMorton Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out. (Stupid cut and paste error, like a darn newbie.)  @NareshDJ Yes, as you discovered, it should have been `s/([^ ]*//`, without the `​\​`.